# jQuery onClick: How to toggle different classes based on window size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've set up this code so that on click of the div. to toggle and remove a class. now i would like to add different classes in different size of windows.
i wrote the below code but this code is not working.
here is my code :

```js
$('.click').click( function() {
  var windowsize = $window.width();
      if (windowsize = 1920) {
    $(".add").toggleClass("new920");
 }
} );
$(".click").click(function(){
   var windowsize = $window.width();
      if (windowsize = 1280) {
    $(".add").toggleClass("new280");
 }
});
```

```css
.click{ border:1px solid #CCC; width:100px; height:20px;}
 .add{ width:200px; height:300px; background:#ccc;}
 .new920{ background:red !important;}
 .new280{ background:green !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  
</head>

<body>
    <div class="click">click</div><br/>
    <div class="add">Add</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should invest some time on Media queries

Comment: change the $window to $(window) and it should work

Comment: @inaz, it is working for you my solution ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai yes. worked.i have send a new post can you review it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `innerWidth` property in order to get `window` size.

If you want `jQuery` version, you have to use `$(window).width()`.

Also, `if` statement accept an `expression`, so you need `if (windowsize == 1920)`.Also, you do not need to bind two `click` event handlers for same element.

```js
$('.click').click( function() {
  var windowsize = window.innerWidth;
  if (windowsize == 1920) {
            $(".add").toggleClass("new920");
  }
         if (windowsize == 1280) {
            $(".add").toggleClass("new280");
         }
});
```

```css
.click{ border:1px solid #CCC; width:100px; height:20px;}
 .add{ width:200px; height:300px; background:#ccc;}
 .new920{ background:red !important;}
 .new1280{ background:green !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  
</head>

<body>
    <div class="click">click</div><br/>
    <div class="add">Add</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: need to use `==` not `=` also whats the use of multiple click handler?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `window` object with a false syntax. It's `$(window)` instead of `$window` ;)

The following should work.

Note: Do you really want to check for a specific width of the window? I assume you rather want to check if the width is smaller than / greater than (`windowsize <= 1280`). Otherwise it's very unlikely that this condition will be met.
Furthermore, you might want to check for `innerWidth()` of the windows size. It's more accurate and represents the size of the space that can display your content.

```js
$('.click').click( function() {
   var windowsize = $(window).width();
    if (windowsize == 1920) {
      $(".add").toggleClass("new920");
    }
});

$(".click").click(function(){
   var windowsize = $(window).width();
   if (windowsize == 1280) {
    $(".add").toggleClass("new280");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

change the `$window` to `$(window)` and it should work